# Getting error while executing a MERGE statement in Hive

Tags: merge, hive, hiveql

I am trying to UPDATE table2 using a certain condition, but getting the following error while using a MERGE statement in HIVE.

Someone please look into my error and provide a solution or correct me if any mistakes in the query.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 A1
USING TABLE2 A2
ON A1.PROJECT_ID=A2.PROJECT_ID 
   AND A1.GREENFIELD_STATUS_CODE=A2.GREENFIELD_STATUS_CODE 
   AND A1.COUNTRY_CODE=A2.COUNTRY_CODE 
   AND A1.PROJECT_NME=A2.PROJECT_NME
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A1.DATETIME_STAMP=A2.DATETIME_STAMP;
```

For the above query I am getting this error:

> HiveServer2Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   ParseException line 24:31 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 'A1'
>   in WHEN MATCHED THEN clause"

So here I am not able to get what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

In your **`match`** statement remove `A1` alias as Merge statement doesn't expect alias.

**Try with this statement:**

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 A1
USING TABLE2 A2
ON A1.PROJECT_ID=A2.PROJECT_ID 
   AND A1.GREENFIELD_STATUS_CODE=A2.GREENFIELD_STATUS_CODE 
   AND A1.COUNTRY_CODE=A2.COUNTRY_CODE 
   AND A1.PROJECT_NME=A2.PROJECT_NME
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET DATETIME_STAMP=A2.DATETIME_STAMP;
```

Refer to [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/update-hive-tables-easy-way/) article for more details regards to Hive-Merge Strategy.